# Oracle group using min date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a statement like this:

```
 select REFNUMBER,
        SomeDate,
        Somecolumn1,
        Somecolumn2
 from Table
```

How can I select the row associated with the lowest date grouped by REFNUMBER ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT REFNUMBER,
         SomeDate,
         Somecolumn1,
         Somecolumn2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY REFNUMBER ORDER BY SomeDate ) As rn
  FROM   Table
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `first/last` aggregate function and avoid a subquery:

```
select   refnumber,
         min(somedate)                                              as somedate,
         min(somecolumn1) keep (dense_rank first order by somedate) as somecolumn1,
         min(somecolumn2) keep (dense_rank first order by somedate,
                                                       somecolumn1) as somecolumn2
from     table_name
group by refnumber
```

Comment: Curiosity, is there an advantage to avoiding a subquery?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - perhaps (although it may be minimal). The best way to find out is to **test** on actual data (rather than on a small sample).

Comment: This has the potential to get values from different rows if there are multiple rows with the same minimum value for the `somedate` column. Imagine row 1: `1, 2017-01-01 00:00:00, 10, 0` and row 2: `1, 2017-01-01 00:00:00, 0, 10` then the output would be `1, 2017-01-01 00:00:00, 0, 0` which takes values from both rows. You can fix it using `ORDER BY somedate, ROWNUM` in the aggregations (or some other method of generating a deterministic ordering of the rows that will ensure only as single row is considered).

Comment: @MT0 :: Right - I wasn't being careful. The correct way to fix this is to add `somecolumn1` to the `order by` in the `first` function applied to `somecolumn2`. Thank you for pointing it out; about half the time I remember to do it right and about half the time I don't.

Answer (score 0):

If there are several **identical lowest** dates by one REFNUMBER, this will give all minimal date rows for this REFNUMBER. (not only one)

```
    SELECT Table.* FROM Table
    INNER JOIN (SELECT REFNUMBER, MIN(SomeDate) AS mindt FROM Table GROUP BY REFNUMBER) t
    ON
    Table.REFNUMBER = t.REFNUMBER AND Table.SomeDate = t.mindt
```

Comment: The same result - without visiting the base table twice - can be obtained from MT0's solution, by using `rank()` or `dense_rank()` (in this case they will give the same result) instead of `row_number()`.